# I can't connect to any wi-fi connection

Tags: wireless

When I try to connect to some wifi  connection, the wifi icon starts glowing and a few seconds later it stops.

It lists the connections so I guess the wifi driver is loaded. if I use the wrong password to wifi it doesn't make any difference and same thing happens without getting the error saying that the password is wrong.

Sad point is that I didn't have this problem with Archlinux or older ubuntu versions.just with ubuntu 17.04

And I should say that wired net works fine.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what wifi card are you using? you might need new drivers

Comment: @ravery lsusb command give this output 
"Ralink Technology, Corp. RT2870/RT3070 Wireless Adapter"
I don't know of I should install something else or not but I know I have a version (maybe corrupt one) because when I blacklist that module  all wifi settings are gone

Comment: https://www.mediatek.com/products/broadbandWifi/rt2870  there are drivers here, you are familiar with compiling kernel mods?

Comment: I can read some manuals. but I have never done it before. and its first time I am encountering .dmg files. But is it necessary? because lsmod shows that "rt2800usb rt2x00usb rt2800lib rt2x00lib" mods are loaded.

Comment: some cards are picky about drivers and generic ones don't work. and since they are kernel modules they have to be compiled for your kernel

Comment: @ravery  Well I never had to install anything. anyway. what am I supposed to do with these files? I managed to extract it but its all about mac stuff. I failed to find anything in the net .  you have some tutorials on what to do with these ?

Comment: hmm those were suposed to be linnux drivers :(